# Вывести инфоблоки частями

Tags: php, битрикс

**Необходимо для определенных элементов инфоблока задать разную верстку :**

По 9 блоков на страницу - затем повтор, снова 9 блоков.

```
<? 
$onePageArrays = array_chunk($arResult["ITEMS"], 9);
?>

<? foreach ($onePageArrays as $onePageArray): ?>

   <? for ($i=0; $i < count($onePageArray); $i++) { ?>

      <? if ($i == 0): ?>
         <h3><?=$arResult["ITEMS"]["$i"]["DISPLAY_PROPERTIES"]["ATT_TITLE"]["DISPLAY_VALUE"]?></h3>

      <? elseif($i >= 1 && $i <= 4): ?>
         <h3><?=$arResult["ITEMS"]["$i"]["DISPLAY_PROPERTIES"]["ATT_TITLE"]["DISPLAY_VALUE"]?></h3>

      <?php else: ?>
         <div></div>

      <?php endif ?>

   <? } ?>

<? endforeach;?>
```

Во втором массиве блок[0] дублирует блок[0] из первого и так далее.

**Как обратится к порядковому номеру текущего массива?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы разделили исходный массив $arResult на части и итерируетесь по ним. НО почему-то вывод делаете из исходного массива, а не його частей.

Код внутри for должен быть другим:

```
  <? if ($i == 0): ?>
     <h3><?=$onePageArray["$i"]["DISPLAY_PROPERTIES"]["ATT_TITLE"]["DISPLAY_VALUE"]?></h3>

  <? elseif($i >= 1 && $i <= 4): ?>
     <h3><?=$onePageArray["$i"]["DISPLAY_PROPERTIES"]["ATT_TITLE"]["DISPLAY_VALUE"]?></h3>

  <?php else: ?>
     <div></div>

  <?php endif ?>
```